# Retrieving groupings from many-to-many tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

This is kind of hard to explain but I'll do what I can.

I have  2 tables with a many-to-many relationship; there is a linking table defining the relationship. These tables are named Question, QuestionTopic and Topic. Topic has the fields TopicID and TopicName.Question has the fields QuestionID and QuestionText.

I want to retrieve a listing of the topics and the number of questions belonging to that topic. However topics could be grouped together and the count of questions unique to that combination should be known. As an example:

Topic(s)           | Count

Topic1,Topic2      |   10

Topic1             |    3

Topic2             |    2

The above implies there are 3 questions unique to topic1 and 10 which have the topics Topic1 and Topic2. The remaining 2 questions have topic2.
I'm using MySQL and PHP. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, this is a very interesting and hard question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Cheating" solution, using `GROUP_CONCAT()`. This will not show the count of questions that are not related to any topic:

```
SELECT
      TopicIds
    , COUNT(*) AS QuestionCount
FROM
      ( SELECT
              QuestionId
            , GROUP_CONCAT(TopicId ORDER BY TopicId) AS Topics
        FROM 
              QuestionTopic
        GROUP BY 
              QuestionId
      ) AS grp
GROUP BY
      Topics
```

Comment: Thanks this works well since questions must be related to a topic. I didn't know about group_concat.

Answer (score 1):

did u try GROUP_CONCAT?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

then, u can group by topic id.

Answer (score 1):

GROUP_CONCAT as mentioned above will work. But on the other side as I see your database structure does not really fit to your task. Looks like it too normalized and you need to do some de-normalization and migration.

Since you have groups of topics I suggest you create two more tables: 
1) TopicGroups: Group | Topic - to list all unique combinations ("groups") of topics in questions.
2) GroupQuestions: Group | Question - to relate question to group of topics it covers

Then the solution for your task will be simple group by query on GroupQuestions.

Comment: How will I populate these tables and when should I do it? It seems like a lot of upkeep.

Comment: initial migration - you will need to write code that does it. Maybe some stored procedure. Its not a simple update/insert thing. Then you will need to insert into these new tables when you insert into original ones - i.e. you either need to write a trigger or change your application. But payoff will be great - performance of the solution will be much better. The cost is usual for de-normalized solutions: 1) there might be data integrity issues, 2) inserts will be slower, 3) insertion code is more complex.